# Rails: random unique array of fixed length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I ensure uniqueness in this array while maintaining its length at `5`?

```
def fixed
  5.times.collect { SecureRandom.random_number(10) }
end
```

This behaviour seems *odd*:

```
5.times.collect.uniq { SecureRandom.random_number(10) }
# => [0, 2, 3, 4]
5.times.collect.uniq { SecureRandom.random_number(10) }
# => [0, 1, 3]
5.times.collect.uniq { SecureRandom.random_number(10) }
# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
5.times.collect.uniq { SecureRandom.random_number(10) }
# => [0, 1, 2, 4]
5.times.collect.uniq { SecureRandom.random_number(10) }
# => [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Do you want an array of 5 numbers which are randomly generated between 0 and 10?

Comment: Need more clarity as to what is needed. Your implementation of it may be not be required for this question. Please some examples of expected sample output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the number of possible values is small – like 10 in your example – then I would generate an array with all options and just pick a random [`sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-sample) of entries:

```
(0..9).to_a.sample(5)
```

If the number of possible values is huge then generation all values first is certainly not an option. Then I would generate a random value as long as the array doesn't contain enough entries:

```
require 'set'
values = Set.new
until values.length == 5 do
  values.add(SecureRandom.random_number(1_000_000))
end
values.to_a
```

Note the I am using a [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) to ensure the uniqueness of the values in the second version.

Comment: But the numbers won't be unique in the output. That's one of the condition.

Comment: @abhishek77in The number **will** be unique. In the first version `sample` only returns unique indexes from the range and in the second version using a `Set` guarantees only unique values (and speeds up the repeated check for duplicates). Why do you think it won't?

Comment: Both yours and mine are drastically inefficient on `size` approaching `max`. Your solution is easier to tweak to switch to `((1..max).to_a - values)` when approaching `size` (where `values` are calculated as is, but treated as  _undesired_.)

Comment: @spickermann each number in the array has to be unique. It's a very clever solution but each number within the array will not be unique in both the cases.

Comment: @spickermann As I mentioned in the comment on the question, the problem is question is not well put.

Comment: @abhishek77in: What do you mean by _each number has to be unique_ and that my solution will _not be unique_? In both versions there *will not duplicates* and I think that is the definition of _unique_. This is guaranteed by `sample` and the use of a `Set`. I do not understand what you think is wrong. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

> One way would be to generate a range of numbers from `0` to `10` and
> then shuffle them to get the unique random numbers.

You can convert that range to Array using [`to_a`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/to_a) and shuffle them using [`shuffle`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/shuffle)

You can do something like this:

```rb
 (0..10).to_a.shuffle[0..4] # => [8, 6, 1, 9, 10]
```

`[0..4]` will give you the first 5 shuffled elements.

Answer (score 2):

Using `SecureRandom`

```
def fixed
  unique_numbers = []

  5.times.collect do 
    loop do
      number = SecureRandom.random_number(10)
      break number unless unique_numbers.include?(number)
    end
  end
end
```

And if you want to generate unique numbers between 1 to 10, then you can create array of 1 to 10 and use `shuffle` or `sample` to get random numbers.

Using [shuffle](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/shuffle)

```
> (0...10).to_a.shuffle.take(5)
=> [4, 0, 1, 3, 7] 
> (0...10).to_a.shuffle.take(5)
=> [6, 2, 3, 9, 1] 
> (0...10).to_a.shuffle.take(5)
=> [9, 2, 5, 8, 4] 
> (0...10).to_a.shuffle.take(5)
=> [5, 0, 6, 8, 7] 
> (0...10).to_a.shuffle.take(5)
=> [2, 7, 1, 5, 0]
```

Using [sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample)

```
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5)
=> [4, 6, 3, 2, 7] 
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5)
=> [5, 8, 2, 3, 7] 
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5)
=> [2, 5, 6, 1, 3] 
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5)
=> [8, 5, 10, 9, 3] 
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5)
=> [8, 1, 5, 3, 4]
```

You can also pass `SecureRandom` custom random generator as an argument with `sample`

```
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5, random: SecureRandom)
 => [6, 3, 4, 7, 10] 
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5, random: SecureRandom)
 => [7, 4, 8, 1, 5] 
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5, random: SecureRandom)
 => [8, 3, 9, 5, 10] 
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5, random: SecureRandom)
 => [6, 8, 9, 2, 1] 
> (1..10).to_a.sample(5, random: SecureRandom)
 => [9, 10, 1, 8, 2]
```

Comment: Whether you use `loop`, it does not need to be nested; check my answer for the clean solution with `loop`.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity, using [`Enumerable#cycle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) infinite generator.

```
MAX = 10
SIZE = 5

[MAX].cycle.inject(Set.new) do |acc, max|
  break acc if acc.size >= SIZE
  acc << SecureRandom.random_number(max)
end
#⇒ #<Set: {2, 1, 7, 0, 9}>
```

or even with generic `loop`:

```
loop.each_with_object(Set.new) do |_, acc|
  break acc if acc.size >= SIZE
  acc << SecureRandom.random_number(10)
end
#⇒ #<Set: {2, 6, 7, 1, 3}>
```